# Eulerian iff Odd Number of Cycle Decompositions

Tags: graph-theory

For this question, Eulerian refers to starting and ending on the same vertex (i.e. being closed).

The graph below is evidently Eulerian. When I look at this graph, I would say it has $2$ cycle decompositions, namely $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and $\{e_4, e_5, e_6\}$.

[image]

However, the corollary below states the number of cycle decompositions must be odd here but the $\# \text{cycle decompositions}=2$ isn't odd...

> So, why would the graph above have an odd number of cycle decompositions here? I feel like I am misinterpreting something.

[image]

The corollary is also found on page 68 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=tqOfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=There%20are%20many%20games%20and%20puzzles%20which%20can%20be%20analysed%20by%20graph%20theoretic%20concepts.%20In%20fact,%20the%20two%20early%20discoveries%20which%20led%20to%20the%20existence%20of%20graphs%20arose%20from%20puzzles,%20namely,%20the%20Konigsberg%20Bridge%20Problem%20and%20Hamiltonian%20Game,%20and%20these%20puzzles%20also%20resulted%20in%20the%20special%20types%20of%20graphs,%20now%20called%20Eulerian%20graphs%20and%20Hamiltonian&source=bl&ots=6ZKwxeZTcc&sig=ACfU3U2eZAvOWWS3ppacKSv17TdX7A2LdQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYiuvh_vboAhVXJ80KHTnwBEYQ6AEwAXoECAwQKQ#v=onepage&q=There%20are%20many%20games%20and%20puzzles%20which%20can%20be%20analysed%20by%20graph%20theoretic%20concepts.%20In%20fact%2C%20the%20two%20early%20discoveries%20which%20led%20to%20the%20existence%20of%20graphs%20arose%20from%20puzzles%2C%20namely%2C%20the%20Konigsberg%20Bridge%20Problem%20and%20Hamiltonian%20Game%2C%20and%20these%20puzzles%20also%20resulted%20in%20the%20special%20types%20of%20graphs%2C%20now%20called%20Eulerian%20graphs%20and%20Hamiltonian&f=false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph has two *cycles*: the cycle $C_1$ made up of edges $e_1, e_2, e_3$, and the cycle $C_2$ made up of edges $e_4, e_5, e_6$.

It has one *cycle decomposition*. A cycle decomposition is a set of cycles that together include all the edges of $G$ exactly once. Here, the set $\{C_1, C_2\}$ is our only cycle decomposition.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now!